# Why the screen becomes dark when an alert was displaying with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-alertdialog

I don't know why the screen becomes dark when I try to use the alert on `initState()` in my flutter application.
This is the code :

```
  if (element.isCharacteristic42) {
             
         
              Scaffold:
              (showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      title: Text('Be Careful an obstacle was detected'),
                      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(45, 231, 148, 54),
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    );
                  }));
            }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Are you directly calling this dialog inside initState ? Can you include full sample widget ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes I'm sirectly calling the dialog inside initState

Comment: Can you include an image that you are trying to archive

Comment: what you're trying to do with this snippet of code ?

Comment: @Gwhyyy this code is incomplete for now I want to show alert on initState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer shadow is provided by `barrierColor` of `showDialog`. You can make it transparent.

And to show dialog inside initState, use `addPostFrameCallback` to complete the first frame

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
```

Comment: Actually I already have s.thg in my screen but when AN alert was Displayed the screen becomes dark

Comment: Can you find any issue on console ?

Comment: no nothing is shown

Comment: Can you include  image on question by pointing the issue

Comment: I accepted your question. It resolved my problem thank you

Comment: Glad to help, more about [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html)